# rxjs - how to merge outer and inner observables

Tags: javascript, rxjs, rxjs6

I have a code that is not working. The goal is to fetch data from API on init and then only from on `click` or `keypress` event. I don't understand how to combine result from `data$`, which should come on init, and then only pick result from events.

`of(res) || merge(event1, event2)` <- not okay

```
const event1 = fromEvent(document, 'click');
const event2 = fromEvent(document, 'keypress');

const data$ = fromFetch('https://api.artic.edu/api/v1/artworks/129884')
  .pipe(
    switchMap((response) => {
      if (response.ok) {
        return response.json();
      } else {
        return of({ error: true, message: `Error ${response.status}` });
      }
    }),
    catchError((err) => {
      console.error(err);
      return of({ error: true, message: err.message });
    }),
  )
  .pipe();

data$
  .pipe(
    switchMap((res) => {
      return (
        of(res) ||
        merge(event1, event2).pipe(
          switchMap((res) => {
            console.log(res);
            return data$;
          }),
        )
      );
    }),
  )
  .subscribe((art) => {
    console.log('Fetched ' + art.data.id);
  });
```

Comment: You want to emit data initially, then also any time event1 or event2 fires?

Comment: @BizzyBob, yes. Fetch on init, and then fetch any time event1 or event2 fires

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close, but not using the merge operator correctly as far as I can tell.

I would do mine something like this:

```js
const event1 = fromEvent(document, 'click');
const event2 = fromEvent(document, 'keypress');
const event3 = of(true); // just to trigger on page load

const data$ = fromFetch('https://api.artic.edu/api/v1/artworks/129884')
  .pipe(
    map((response) => {
      if (response.ok) {
        return response.json();
      } else {
        return { error: true, message: `Error ${response.status}` };
      }
    }),
    catchError((err) => {
      console.error(err);
      return of({ error: true, message: err.message });
    }),
  );

  const merged = merge(event1, event2, event3);

  merged.pipe(
    switchMap(event => $data)
  ).subscribe();

  event3.pipe(take(1)).subscribe(); // triggers the fetch on load.
```

EDIT: [Merge documentation](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/merge) for reference

Comment: Yeah, so merge should be as a parent observable. I also found `startWith` operator. So my code looks like this for now. Not sure if it is okay.

`merge(event1, event2)
  .pipe(
    startWith(data$),
    switchMap(() => data$),
  )
  .subscribe((art) => {
    console.log(art);
    console.log('Fetched ' + art.data.id);
  });`

Comment: StartWith will work fine, but note the argument you pass it should be a plain value, not an observable. In your case, you don’t use the value at all, so you can just pass undefined.